# What is the shortest snippet that emulates `include` in JavaScript without third-party scripts?

Tags: javascript, dom, http, modules

JavaScript doesn't offer a module system. There are many third-party solutions, like `require.js` or jQuery's `$.getScript`. Most, while good, they bring dependencies, extra kbs and/or limit your folder structures. Sometimes it's necessary to make a .js file self-sufficient. This said, what is the smallest snippet that can be inserted at the top of a .js file, which will emulate "import", so it can load other scripts before running itself?

The .js file should look like this, for example. Notice the addition is just a small one-liner:

```
(function(i,m,p,o,r,t){for(p=i.length,o=0;o<p;++o){r=(t=document).createElement('script');r.src=i[o];r.onload=function(){!--p&&m()};t.head.appendChild(r); }; })
(['http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js','http://underscorejs.org/underscore-min.js'],
function main(){
    console.log('jQuery loaded:',$);
    console.log('underscore.js loaded:',_);
});
```

For clarity, the top function above, expanded, is equivalent to:

```
(function (u, f, l, i, a, d) {
        for (l = u.length, i = 0; i < l; ++i) {
            a = (d = document).createElement('script');
            a.src = u[i];
            a.onload = function () {
                !--l && f()
            };
            d.head.appendChild(a);
        };
    })
```

Can this be minimized even further?

Comment: Awful and should't be done, but http://www.phpied.com/javascript-include/

Comment: @jacktheripper care to explain?

Comment: @Dokkat If you wish for people to make suggestions about how this could be improved, it's best not to minify it.

Comment: @JonathanSampson I don't want to improve upon my code, it's just to show the concept. I was expecting there to be something much better.

Comment: @Dokkat Fine, if you want people to understand *the concept*, don't make it more difficult by providing minified code.

Comment: Smallest as in smallest footprint? Would that include ugly and slow packers that obfuscates?

Comment: @JonathanSampson but the code is not 'minified', I have already coded it small for the purpose... I can increase it if you want to - do you? But that's nothing complicated, it just takes an array of strings (argument 1), adds every string to document.head as a <script> tag and runs the callback (argument 2) when those are all loaded. The other arguments are internal.

Comment: Are you using all of those initial args as a way to avoid using var to define them in your block?

Comment: Yes, p, o, r and t are for avoiding var, as it is 4 chars long.

Comment: @Dokkat I've taken the liberty of improving the code's readability. When much of it is on one line, and full of single-char variables, it doesn't lend itself to being easily understood.

Comment: `document.head` is not avail in IE8-. Care to add browser compat and other "rules"?

Comment: @Dokkat Jesus, stop minifying your code. I'm trying to read it! `:P`

Comment: @JonathanSampson thank you very much for the edit, but sorry, I had to rollback. The whole idea is to using a compact one liner on the top of the file. Expanding it makes the idea unclear. We could add the function expanded after the snippet. What do you think?

Comment: @Dokkat You can minify whenever you go to use in production. Don't minify it here - it is here to be read and understood. You are not helping the community by insisting upon hard-to-read formatting. I'm asking again, please leave it legible or remove the question.

Comment: @JonathanSampson again, it does not demonstrate the idea if the function is huge with many lines. The idea is to have a compact, minified code to include on the top of a .js file, that will not distract a reader from the actual code. Please try to understand what I'm saying!

Comment: @Dokkat are you writing software for consumption by 28.8bps modems?

Comment: http://dean.edwards.name/packer/

Comment: This was my most misunderstood question. Thank you all anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most JavaScript libraries add properties to the window object so one alternative would be to test for those properties. For example

```
m = [ "$", //jQuery
      "_"  // underscore.js
    ];
tries = 5000;
(function loaded( ) {
    var i = m.length;

    while( i-- ) {
        if( !window[m[i]] ) { 
            return --tries ? setTimeout( loaded, 1 ) : failed();
        }
    }
    done();  
}())
```

And in one line it looks like this

```
m=["$","_"];tries=5e3;(function e(){var t=m.length;while(t--){if(!window[m[t]]){return--tries?setTimeout(e,1):failed()}}done()})()
```

Comment: I don't think this is really relevant. The question is not how to detect the all of the external dependencies have been loaded.

Comment: To be honest, while this doesn't answer, it's better than the other answers as it (almost) does what I asked. I'll stay with my own snippet this time. );

Answer (score 2):

Here is what I do:

```
var a_script= document.createElement('script');
a_script.src = 'http://www.blah.com/some_script.js';
document.head.appendChild(a_script);
```

I should mention that in production I pretty much always combine all javascript files into one larger, minified, and google [closure compiled file](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/gettingstarted_ui).

Comment: He's actually doing the same thing, but his fires off on the load event so it's a little more precise.

Comment: I do almost the same thing, I usually append to the `body` though.

Answer (score 2):

I normally wouldn't suggest to compress this specific JavaScript file. The reason is because it's really powerful technique what you are trying to achieve, and it's on the included files where you need to put the effort on the compression, as they will tend to be longer than such a script as you are describing.

I personally use the following snippet, which I consider short because I have seen that it's unobtrusive, not sure if it's shorter than the one you are suggesting.

```
//JP_js-css_request.js

<!-- Append js and css to the <head> of the document on demand based on the page -->

function loadjscssfile(filename, filetype){

    switch (filetype)
    {
        case "js":
        {
            var fileref=document.createElement('script')

            fileref.setAttribute("type","text/javascript");
            fileref.setAttribute("src", filename);
        }
        break;

        case "css":
        {
            var fileref=document.createElement("link")
            fileref.setAttribute("rel", "stylesheet");
            fileref.setAttribute("type", "text/css");
            fileref.setAttribute("href", filename);
        }
        break;

        default: break;
    }


    if (typeof fileref!="undefined")  document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(fileref)
}

var filesadded="" //list of files already added

function checkloadjscssfile(filename, filetype){
    if (filesadded.indexOf("["+filename+"]")==-1){
        loadjscssfile(filename, filetype)
        filesadded+="["+filename+"]" //add to list of files already added, in the form of "[filename1],[filename2],etc"
    }
}
```

I place this script in the head as  and when I want to call a CSS or JS to be re-used but I want to check if it's been included already at the head we call `loadjscssfile( [path_to_file/filename.extension]`, js or css.

That for me takes care of it.  Also keeping this file editable (as it kind of short) allows you to do modifications that can affect many files and centralizing the process.  Or for example if you want to add import for CSS, etc.  One thing to mention is that if you are including jQuery libraries or Prototype, or Scriptaculous etc, you need to be careful to call this file at the end `</head>`.  The reason is that if it appends the file after a library can affect the bindings of functions related by another library.

So in short if you have

```
jQuery
jQuery UI v-xxx
Mootools
Scriptaculous
Prototype
```

libraries, you need to not only avoid conflict between libraries but to ensure that all JS framework or heavy stuff are loaded firstly.  That ensures that you can call files to append to the head just after the JavaScript file is included. So far, it has heavily helped me out because I use http://jscompress.com and after checking a JS works good on a project, I compress the file and call `loadjscssfile()` as a function over that one. Although sometimes it takes some time to load depending on how big the resource is.

Comment: Also, you should look into this framework, might be just what you are looking for. EnhanceJS version 1.1 - Test-Driven Progressive Enhancement * http://enhancejs.googlecode.com/

Answer (score 0):

I advise against your "smallest" approach, I think you set your priorities wrong.

IMO you should avoid:

- Minifying non-production code, as processing time is cheaper than developer time;
- Premature optimization, such as declaring extra arguments to save 4 characters by avoiding using var (for 3 variables, that is 1.3 characters saved per variable);
- Using variables with 3 or less characters, 1-char variables being the Megazord of this flaw.

All these things will reduce the readability and maintainability of your code. And **what for?** The gain is infinitesimal, and the risk is large.

Just including the minified JQuery you give as an example increases the code by **93 thousand** characters. What is the use of worrying about saving 50 characters out of 100k?

You can implement your JS normally and then minify in production, you can reduce image sizes, you can use CSS sprites... there are a lot of better ways to save bandwidth.
(YMMV)